# Why MediaStore.Images.Media give me only BitMap while on the phone images are JPG

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I'm "playing" with `MediaStore.Images.Media` and I saw that I can only retrieve `BMP` format (`MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail()` - `MediaStore.Images.Media.getThumbnail()`), while the same images on my device actually are `JPG`.

I didn't find any clear explanation on the internet.

Can anybody help me understand better?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getThumbnail()` returns a `Bitmap`. This has nothing to do with the BMP file format. A `Bitmap` is a decoded image, regardless of the encoding of whatever the image came from (JPEG, PNG, WebP, GIF, BMP, etc.).